# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 when working with objc_setAssociatedObject

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, runtime

This is the run time error log I am getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_MyConstantKey", referenced from:
      -[LayoutViewController addLabelsAndButtonInBaseView:withLayoutObject:] in LayoutViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

I am trying to pass an object along with UIButton selector.

this is my code:

this is how I am declaring a var:

```
extern const char MyConstantKey;
@interface LayoutViewController : UIViewController
```

my implementation file :

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

and relevant code for setting associated object:

```
UIButton *componentButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:baseView.bounds];
objc_setAssociatedObject(componentButton,
                         MyConstantKey,
                         layout,
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
[componentButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(componentButtonPressed:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[componentButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

any suggestion? Is there any framework which I am missing,

Comment: How did you declared MyConstantKey?

Comment: @Vladimir extern const char MyConstantKey, see in header file, should i made it to extern const Layout *MyConstantKey?

Comment: How did you **define** `MyConstantKey`?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe as i understand from OBJC_EXPORT void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, const void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy):   in my context object is componentButton, key is declared as MYConstantKey, value is the layout object, and policy is OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring variable as extern only prompts to compiler that variable will be created somewhere possibly outside of current compilation unit. So you need to actually create it in your implementation file. Also I think using char* instead of char here will be more appropriate:

```
// .h
extern const char* MyConstantKey;

// .m 
const char* MyConstantKey = "MyConstantKey"; 

…
objc_setAssociatedObject(componentButton,
                         (void*)MyConstantKey,
                         layout,
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

Comment: @thank you very much, it was the very first time i was trying to implement associated feature, basically i dont want to keep unnecessary class variables/properties.are there any side effects. or say cons of using them, what are the pointer i should keep in mind: for example memory usage, release(in arc???), some thing else ,

Answer (score 1):

Define your custom property like this way

```
#define kCustomProperty @"CustomProperty"
```

Associate your object with that custom property like below

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(myObj,kCustomProperty , myData, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Get your data using the same property and object like below

```
NSObject *aObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(myObj, kCustomProperty);
```

Comment: `objc_setAssociatedObject()` uses the pointer itself as the key, not the contents of the string. It is not guaranteed (as far as I know) that a string literal has the same address when used in different places. Therefore I would not recommend this solution.