# Uniquely identify two different views

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, tags, uibutton

I have two buttons/views in Main view with same name , same tag and same event called when any button is pressed. Then,how to differentiate which button is pressed ?

Please do not suggest to change name or tag of button because my application is too large so changing name or tag in whole application is tedious work.

Is there any other way to differentiate two buttons/views?

Comment: I had answered the same answer for this question as well just one line added at the bottom, have a look:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740460/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-when-working-with-objc-setassociatedobj/20741134#20741134

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your custom property like this way

```
#define kCustomProperty @"CustomProperty"
```

Associate your object with that custom property like below

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(myObj,kCustomProperty , myData, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Get your data using the same property and object like below

```
NSObject *aObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(myObj, kCustomProperty);
```

Its a kind of custom property you can create by coding if you don't want to use tag or change name of view
.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do and it seems like you should consider changing your design. That being said, you can distinguish between two buttons\views base on many parameters: position, size, color, title... This really depends on how you create and set them and by how they differ from one another.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example distinguish them by where they are located within their superview. If one is above or to the right of the other.